# Display go button instead of return in textarea for android soft keyboard

Tags: android, css, html

I'm developing a mobile web application that contains a form with a textarea. Android, with the textarea on focus displays a Return button instead of Go button.

Is it possible to force the android soft keyboard to display a Go button instead of Return?

NOTE: it's a web application hence HTML not java